# Adding new value to String array based on condition

Tags: c#, arrays

String Array contains values like  {'2','4','8'}

if 8 is present, want to add 999 to it,if string array contains 999 want to add 8 to it.

If both 8 and 999 are present in array no need to add any value to array.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post piece of your code and more specific error. The array doesn't even seems to be C# string array, but only char array.

Comment: Can you show your code and the effort you try to solve it?

Comment: what to do when array contains both `8` and `999`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following:

```
public string[] Add8or999(string[] source)
{
    string[] output = source;
    if (source.Contains("8") && source.Contains("999"))
    {
        // what to do here? 
    }
    else if (source.Contains("8"))
    {
        output = new string[source.Length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            output[i] = source[i];  
        }
        output[source.Length] = "999";
    }
    else if (source.Contains("999"))
    {
        output = new string[source.Length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            output[i] = source[i];  
        }
        output[source.Length] = "8";
    }
    return output;
}
```

**Basic Usage:**

```
string[] s = Add8or999(new string[] {"8", "9", "10"});
```